# Forever run `npm start` can't find '/package.json'

Tags: node.js, forever

I'm trying to run `npm start` and keep it running forever. So I executed the following command `forever -c "npm start" /home/deploy/frontend` where the path provided leads to my sourcefolder of my Angular 2 application.

When I run `npm start` in that folder, a lite-server starts and everything works fine. With this command however, it's trying to access `/package.json`, but since I'm running on Linux, this will not result into `..../frontend/package.json` but just `/package.json`.

Is there some way of configuring `forever` to run the scripts from my `/home/deploy/frontend/package.json`?

The logs (just snipped out 1 out of 3 attempts):

```
:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - error: Script restart attempt #3
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-72-generic
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" "/home/deploy/frontend"
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! node v7.10.0
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! path /package.json
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! code ENOENT
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! errno -2
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! syscall open
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! enoent
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-06-19T08_39_29_496Z-debug.log
data:    /home/deploy/frontend:28134 - error: Forever detected script exited with code: 254
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to execute:

```
forever start -c "npm start" /home/deploy/frontend/
```

or, if that fails, from your application directory:

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

Comment: Nope, it still tries to access `/package.json`, same error as in my question

Comment: Try executing it directly from your application folder and check the results: forever start -c "npm start" ./

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you create a project inside a folder with same project or package name. Try creating the project in a different folder so that react framework can look out for package.json file while building